# grep at the beginning of the string with fixed =T in R?

Tags: r, regex

How to grep with `fixed=T`, but only at the beginning of the string?

```
grep("a.", c("a.b", "cac", "sss", "ca.f"), fixed = T)
# 1 4
```

I would like to get only the first occurrence. 
[Edit: the string to match is not known in advance, and can be anything. "a." is just for the sake of example]

Thanks.

[Edit: I sort of solved it now, but any other ideas are highly welcome. I will accept as an answer any alternative solution.

```
s <- "a."
res <- grep(s, c("a.b", "cac", "sss", "ca.f"), fixed = T, value = T)
res[substring(res, 1, nchar(s)) == s]
```

]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to match an exact string (string 1) at the beginning of the string (string 2), then just subset your string 2 to be the same length as string 1 and use ==, should be fairly fast.

Comment: Just astonishing how sometimes the eyes don't see the obvious! `res[substring(res, 1 ,nchar(s))== s]` in my solution does exactly this thing! Thanks Greg, for waking me up.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, Greg -and you- have mentioned the cleanest solution already. I would even drop the grep altogether:

```
> name <- "a#"
> string <- c("a#b", "cac", "sss", "ca#f")
> string[substring(string, 1, nchar(name)) == name]
[1] "a#b"
```

But if you really insist on grep, you can use Dwins approach, or following mindboggling solution:

```
specialgrep <- function(x,y,...){
  grep(
    paste("^",
          gsub("([].^+?|[#\\-])","\\\\\\1",x)
          ,sep=""),
    y,...)
}
> specialgrep(name,string,value=T)
[1] "a#b"
```

It might be I forgot to include some characters in the gsub. Be sure you keep the ] symbol first and the - last in the characterset, otherwise you'll get errors. Or just forget about it, use your own solution. This one is just for fun's sake :-)

Comment: +1 for "just for fun" solution, which is in fact easelly extensible to adress more involved problems, when only some "regexp" symbols are used and any others have to be backslashed.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to use `fixed=T` because of the `.` in the pattern? In that case you can just escape the `.` this would work:

```
grep("^a\\.", c("a.b", "cac", "sss", "ca.f"))
```

Comment: The name can be anything and I don't know it in advance, it can contain "." or any other regexp character like \,|,[ etc. This is why i need fixed=T

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the focus on the first two characters, then only present that much information to grep:

```
> grep("a.", substr(c("a.b", "cac", "sss", "ca.f"), 1,2) ,fixed=TRUE)
[1] 1
```

You could easily wrap it into a function:

```
> checktwo <- function (patt,vec) { grep(patt, substr(vec, 1,nchar(patt)) ,fixed=TRUE) }
> checktwo("a.", c("a.b", "cac", "sss", "ca.f") )
[1] 1
```

Comment: "a." is just for the sake of example. It can be sds.s.[\sf^sdf for example. I've edited my post to clarify this.

Comment: Then all you need to do is substitute nchar(patt) as the third argument to substr.

Answer (score 1):

I think Dr. G had the key to the solution in his answer, but didn't explicitly call it out: "^" in the pattern specifies "at the beginning of the string".  ("$" means at the end of the string)

So his "^a." pattern means "at the beginning of the string, look for an 'a' followed by one character of anything [the '.']".

Or you could just use "^a" as the pattern unless you don't want to match the one character string containing only "a".

Does that help?

Jeffrey

Comment: I can't use ^ because of fixed=T