# R: gsub of exact full string with fixed = T

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I am trying to `gsub` exact FULL string - I know I need to use `^` and `$`. The problem is that I have special characters in strings (could be `[`, or `.`) so I need to use `fixed=T`. This overrides the `^` and `$`. Any solution is appreciated. 
Need to replace 1st, 2nd element in `exact_orig` with 1st, 2nd element from `exact_change` but only if full string is matched from beginning to end.

```
exact_orig = c("oz","32 oz")
exact_change = c("20 oz","32 ct")

gsub_FixedTrue <- function(i) {
  for(k in seq_along(exact_orig)) i = gsub(exact_orig[k],exact_change[k],i,fixed=TRUE)
  return(i)
}
```

Test cases:

```
print(gsub_FixedTrue("32 oz")) #gives me "32 20 oz" - wrong! Must be "32 ct"
print(gsub_FixedTrue("oz oz")) # gives me "20 oz 20 oz" - wrong! Must remain as "oz oz"
```

I read a somewhat similar thread, but could not make it work for full string ([grep at the beginning of the string with fixed =T in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477638/grep-at-the-beginning-of-the-string-with-fixed-t-in-r))

Comment: I am confused about the conditions, please give some more example inputs and outputs, and give some examples when the condition is met, this seems fairly simple and not requiring any regex, but I am unsure as to what you are trying to accomplish, something like `Map(function(x, y) ifelse(x == y, y, x), exact_orig, exact_change)`

Comment: "oz" must be changed to "20 oz" only if the whole string is "oz". Thus "oz oz" should stay as "oz oz"

Comment: Can you try to elaborate on the pattern you are trying to extract? Including symbols like `[` or `.` does *not* necessitate using `fixed = TRUE`.

Comment: word like `ca[` goes into 'cap'. But again, only if full string is met, not in `ca[ test`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to exactly match full strings, i don't think you really want to use regular expressions in this case. How about just the `match()` function

```
fixedTrue<-function(x) {
    m <- match(x, exact_orig)
    x[!is.na(m)] <- exact_change[m[!is.na(m)]]
    x
}

fixedTrue(c("32 oz","oz oz"))
# [1] "32 ct" "oz oz"
```

Comment: How simple and elegant! THANK YOU!

Comment: What if I want to do the substitute only if another condition is met? Let's say, change `32 oz` to `32 ct` if some `flag == 1` but not when `flag != 1`. `flag` will belong to `x` and will come from another column in same dataframe

Comment: Then you just need to do the appropriate indexing of the vectors involved. If you are unsure how to do that, that seems like a new/different question. I suggest you at least make a first attempt, if you are unsuccessful, start a new question showing the code you tried and describing how it didn't work. One shouldn't ask new questions in comments on Stack Overflow.

Comment: OK. Tried a couple of things, but was not successful with a new test case. Will ask a diff question. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30920000/matching-a-pattern-with-match-with-extra-condition